# Is there a better way to handle api calls in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've build a function to make an api call to a weather service and then update state based on if it resolves, or rejects. The code works perfectly, but it feels messy to me.

```
getForecastedWeather(){
    const endpoint = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/207931?apikey=mG0ISFW1ZGGHIV3rs5CSFQlF92CYSqhr&language=en&details=true&metric=true`;
    const fetchPromise = fetch(endpoint);

    fetchPromise
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            forecasts: {
                ...state.forecasts,
                error: null,
                isLoaded:true,
                forecasts:result.DailyForecasts
            },
        }));
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            forecasts: { 
                ...state.forecasts, 
                error, 
                isLoaded:false 
            },
        }));
    })
}
```

Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Try axios library for requests/response

Comment: Your code can be more succinct if you use `await`.

Comment: You could try `async...await` syntax to improve the readibility and overall structure of the code. Also, you could look into `finally()` in Promise interface.

Comment: @Biranchi Pulling-in an entire library just for shorter `fetch` call-sites is overkill.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you feel it is messy so that perhaps someone can respond with suggestions to make it feel less messy to you?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using `async` `await` syntax:

```
async getForecastedWeather(){
  try {
    const endpoint = `http://...`;
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const result = await response.json();
    this.setState(state => ({ ... }));
  } catch (error) {
    this.setState(state => ({ ... }));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can `await fetch` directly. There's no need to save the reference to the `Promise<Response>` object.

Comment: Also this is wrong: `await fetchPromise();` - `fetchPromise` is not a function.

Comment: My preference is not to use try/catch synta

Comment: @johnst123v Your "preference" is irrelevant. You **have** to use `try { } catch ( err ) { }` with `async`/`await` - otherwise you have to go back to using the old-style of `.then().catch()`, which defeats the purpose you asking this question in the first place..